# how to keep a column when i do grouping in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, max

so i want to show 3 columns:

- created_at
- category
- quantity

[image]

so, how to get maximum in quantity by grouping created_at while category follows max quantity?

here is my code

```
tb = (merge_all.groupby(["created_at", "category"])
        .agg({ 
            "buyer_id":"count", 
            "quantity":"sum",
            "total":"sum"
            })
        .reset_index()
        .sort_values(by = "quantity", ascending=False))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
merge_all.groupby("created_at").apply(lambda x: x.sort_values("quantity", ascending=False))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).